# Non-used variable impacts program

Tags: c, variables

i have to write a small c program for university, which should print the given parameters again on the command line. The task is to do it with pointers. 
So my problem is, the program works totally right when the unused variable "bin" is part of the code. But if i try to delete the code or comment it out, the program isn't working anymore (it crashes or doesn't print anything)... But the variable is not used in the program at all. Also i am also able to change the name of it but not its declarated value. Maybe someone can help/ explain what the problem is :)
Thank you!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *text;
    char bin = '\0'; //<---- unused variable
    char space = 32;
    int i = 0;

    if(argc == 1){
        printf("Bitte Parameter mit angeben!");
        return 1;
    }

    text = malloc(sizeof(char));

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        text = realloc(text, sizeof(char) * (strlen(argv[i]) + 2 + 
               strlen(text)));
        if(text == NULL)
            return 1;
        text = strcat(text, argv[i]);
        text = strcat(text, &space);
    }

    text++;
    printf("%s", text);
    free(text);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What changes? What's the problem? If it's not used, it's not used. You'd have to have some bizarre UB or something for that to effect anything.

Comment: If the variable is part of the program, the program prints out the given parameters. But if its missing, the program crashes or doesnt print anything...

Comment: Crashes with what error?

Comment: You can't append to `text` before you initialise the memory region it points to.; that's Undefined Behaviour, and the actual behaviour can be anything (which means it can vary depend on things which you might think were irrelevant. By the way, `sizeof char` is always one.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` _always_ - by definition.

Comment: if this statement: `char *text;`  is changed to `char *text = NULL;`  then the call to `malloc()` can be eliminated.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc): 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, save the returned value to a temp variable, check the temp variable and if not NULL, then assign to the target variable  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak. 3) regarding: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as always 1,  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: in the call to `realloc()`, this expression: `strlen(text)));` invokes undefined behavior as the allocated memory pointed to by `text` contains random characters so where the `strlen()` will encounter a NUL byte (especially on the first pass through the loop) random,

Comment: regarding: `text++;`  why do you want to skip the first character?

Comment: the variable `bin` needing to be there is just a result of the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = strcat(text, &space);
```

This line is taking the address of a single character variable, and then passing it to `strcat` which expects a nul-terminated string argument.  The fact that it works with the `bin` variable probably means that your compiler has chosen to place the variables next to each other on the stack in such a way that it treats it as the nul-terminator; however, relying on this is certainly undefined behavior.

It would be better to actually provide a string literal or constant, e.g.:

```
const char space[] = " ";
...
text = strcat(text, space);
```

or simply:

```
text = strcat(text, " ");
```

Note that while this may resolve your immediate problem, there are other issues in the code as well that others have pointed out.  Specifically, using `text` in `strlen` before initializing the allocated memory and freeing `text` after the pointer has been moved are both undefined behavior, and I expect you are again just lucky that it happens to work for now.

Comment: @PhilippHofer : It may appear to work, but the code has other serious errors not addressed in this answer.  Failing to initialise the memory pointed to by `text` and free'ing the _modified_ `text` pointer are also serious errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your code concatenates to `text` without initialising `text`.  You need to start with `text` as an empty string:

```
text = malloc(sizeof(char));
text[0] = `\0` ; // empty string
```

Then passing `&space` to `strcat()` is erroneous since `space` is not a nul terminated string.  Simply replace with:

```
text = strcat(text, " " ) ;
```

Then later remove the `text++` otherwise it will omit the first character, and you cannot `free()` the modified pointer without causing a heap error:

```
// text++;   <<< NOT NEEDED and makes free(text) bound to fail.
printf("%s", text);
free( text ) ;
```

Why it worked with `bin` present is because you got lucky and it happened to form the nul terminator to `&space` due to adjacency on the stack.  You got lucky again with whatever `text` pointed to without initialisation, and free'ing the modified pointer may not have caused an error or fault because the program ends without attempting to allocate any further memory.